# segmentation fault in singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am currently writing a program that implements a linked list to maintain a list on integers in sorted order.  The program reads the integers from a file in the format of

```
d [\t] 7
i [\t] 8
i [\t] 7
i [\t] 10
```

with 'd' meaning delete from the list and 'i' inserting into the list, with no repeat integers allowed.  This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
        int data;
        struct Node* next;
};

int delete(struct Node** head, int key){
        if(head == NULL)
        {
                return -1;
        }
        struct Node* ptr = *head;
        struct Node* prev = NULL;

        while(ptr->data != key && ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
                prev = ptr;
                ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        if(ptr->data == key)
        {
                if(prev)
                {
                        prev->next = ptr->next;
                }
                else
                {
                        *head = ptr->next;
                }
                free(ptr);
                return key;
        }
return -1;
}

int insert(struct Node** head, struct Node* newNode){
        struct Node* ptr;
        if(*head == NULL || (*head)->data >= newNode->data)
        {
        newNode->next = *head;
                *head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
                ptr = *head;
                while(ptr->next != NULL && ptr->next->data < newNode->data)
                {
                        ptr = ptr->next;
                }
                newNode->next = ptr->next;
                ptr->next = newNode;
        }
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        int num, found;
        char c;
        struct Node* head = NULL;
 struct Node* ptr = head;
        while(fscanf(fp, "%c\t%d\n", &c, &num)!=EOF)
        {
                for(ptr=head; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->next)
                {
                        if(ptr->data == num)
                        {
                                found = 1;
                        }
                }
                if(found != 1)
                {
                        if(c == 'i')
                        {
                                struct Node *newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                                newNode->data = num;
                                newNode->next = NULL;
                                insert(&head, newNode);
                        }
                }
                if(c == 'd')
  delete(&head, num);
                }
                found = 0;
        }

        for(ptr=head; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->next)
        {
                printf("%d ", ptr->data);
        }
return 0;
}
```

It works fine when the first letter is 'i', but whenever the first letter is 'd' I get a segmentation fault. Why is this?

Comment: May not be the problem, but you need to initialise things esp `found`

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If key is not in the list, when ptr equals to tail in while loop check, in the body of the while loop  ptr = ptr->next will cause ptr to be NULL and in the next iteration, ptr->data will cause segmentation fault since you would be trying to derefence a NULL pointer.

Comment: `while(ptr-....` - `ptr` could be null!

Answer (score 2):

When you try to delete a node first thing you do, the list is empty and inside the `delete` function `*head` (notice the dereference!) is a null pointer.

Since `*head` is a null pointer, so will `ptr` be, and you then dereference `ptr` without checking for that.

You might want to modify the initial check to be `head == NULL || *head == NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

`whenever the first letter is 'd' I get a segmentation fault.`

If the first letter is D,  your list is still empty when you call `delete`.

In your first `if`, you need to dereference your pointer, as @SomeProgrammerDude mentionned.